# How to make content editable in Rails without using a CMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a dynamic web app that each paragraph could be editable with one click. Just wondering if anyone has any recommendation's how I could go about that without using a CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to ckeditor :
gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'

Answer (score 0):

This type of implementation sounds like more of a JavaScript question.  You'll need to look into the rails API and may need to disable turbolinks.

You can even use the rails generator for scaffolding to build out your models and controllers.  I'd recommend nesting two models.

```
rails generate scaffold Article title:string author:string
rails generate scaffold Paragraph content:text article:references
```

At this point you will need to wire up your javascript editor to your update method in the controller.